# BindingNavigator c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde!

Estou usando o bindingNavigator do C# para cadastrar dados ao banco de dados, porém não gosto de como é feito o processo com os botões lá em cima e ter que clicar naquele botão amarelo de mais pra incluir um novo registro.

Ao clicar no botão de salvar o visual studio me apresenta o seguinte código:

```
        this.Validate();
        this.tIPOPAGAMENTOBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.fINANCEIRODataSet);
```

Inclui ele em meu botão porém os dados são salvos somente no banco quando o botão addnew (amarelo do print ) e clicado, gostaria de saber se alguém sabe o que faz este botão que habilita o dataSet para edição para que seja salvo no banco, não quero ter que clicar nele toda vez que for adicionar um registro novo, alguem pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vê se te atende esses exemplos: Cadastro Simples Windows Forms: [Link1](http://magazine.softerize.com.br/tutoriais/net/cadastrando-dados-banco-com-c-windows-forms), [Link2](http://pt.slideshare.net/AndrLuiz34/cadastro-de-clientes-em-c)